# zend framework2 tutorial: Fatal error: Class 'Album\Model\AlbumTable' not found in C:\wamp\www\quickstart\module\Album\Module.php

Tags: zend-framework, zend-framework2

NOTES: Development is done in Netabean IDE, hosting is local on WAMPP, I have it configured for a virtual host. Composer is being used.

I have reviewed other questions similar to this and I do not have the same issue. Please note this is my first time using Zend framework. Thank you.

The use of echos helped me locate that when I create my AlbumTable in Module.php it fails.

Here is the Stacktrace:

> [30-Mar-2015 20:29:11 Europe/Paris] PHP Fatal error:  Class
>   'Album\Model\AlbumTable' not found in
>   C:\wamp\www\quickstart\module\Album\Module.php on line 43
>
> [30-Mar-2015 20:29:11 Europe/Paris] PHP Stack trace:
>
> [30-Mar-2015 20:29:11 Europe/Paris] PHP   1. {main}()
>   C:\wamp\www\quickstart\public\index.php:0
>
> [30-Mar-2015 20:29:11 Europe/Paris] PHP   2.
>   Zend\Mvc\Application->run() C:\wamp\www\quickstart\public\index.php:26
>
> [30-Mar-2015 20:29:11 Europe/Paris] PHP   3.
>   Zend\EventManager\EventManager->trigger()
>   C:\wamp\www\quickstart\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\Mvc\Application.php:313
>
> [30-Mar-2015 20:29:11 Europe/Paris] PHP   4.
>   Zend\EventManager\EventManager->triggerListeners()
>   C:\wamp\www\quickstart\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\EventManager\EventManager.php:207
>
> [30-Mar-2015 20:29:11 Europe/Paris] PHP   5.
>   call_user_func:{C:\wamp\www\quickstart\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\EventManager\EventManager.php:468}()
>   C:\wamp\www\quickstart\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\EventManager\EventManager.php:468
>
> [30-Mar-2015 20:29:12 Europe/Paris] PHP   6.
>   Zend\Mvc\DispatchListener->onDispatch()
>   C:\wamp\www\quickstart\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\EventManager\EventManager.php:468
>
> [30-Mar-2015 20:29:12 Europe/Paris] PHP   7.
>   Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractController->dispatch()
>   C:\wamp\www\quickstart\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\Mvc\DispatchListener.php:113
>
> [30-Mar-2015 20:29:12 Europe/Paris] PHP   8.
>   Zend\EventManager\EventManager->trigger()
>   C:\wamp\www\quickstart\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractController.php:116
>
> [30-Mar-2015 20:29:12 Europe/Paris] PHP   9.
>   Zend\EventManager\EventManager->triggerListeners()
>   C:\wamp\www\quickstart\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\EventManager\EventManager.php:207
>
> [30-Mar-2015 20:29:12 Europe/Paris] PHP  10.
>   call_user_func:{C:\wamp\www\quickstart\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\EventManager\EventManager.php:468}()
>   C:\wamp\www\quickstart\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\EventManager\EventManager.php:468
>
> [30-Mar-2015 20:29:12 Europe/Paris] PHP  11.
>   Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController->onDispatch()
>   C:\wamp\www\quickstart\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\EventManager\EventManager.php:468
>
> [30-Mar-2015 20:29:12 Europe/Paris] PHP  12.
>   Album\Controller\AlbumController->indexAction()
>   C:\wamp\www\quickstart\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController.php:83
>
> [30-Mar-2015 20:29:12 Europe/Paris] PHP  13.
>   Album\Controller\AlbumController->getAlbumTable()
>   C:\wamp\www\quickstart\module\Album\src\Album\Controller\AlbumController.php:26
>
> [30-Mar-2015 20:29:12 Europe/Paris] PHP  14.
>   Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager->get()
>   C:\wamp\www\quickstart\module\Album\src\Album\Controller\AlbumController.php:51
>
> [30-Mar-2015 20:29:12 Europe/Paris] PHP  15.
>   Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager->create()
>   C:\wamp\www\quickstart\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager.php:525
>
> [30-Mar-2015 20:29:12 Europe/Paris] PHP  16.
>   Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager->doCreate()
>   C:\wamp\www\quickstart\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager.php:593
>
> [30-Mar-2015 20:29:12 Europe/Paris] PHP  17.
>   Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager->createFromFactory()
>   C:\wamp\www\quickstart\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager.php:633
>
> [30-Mar-2015 20:29:12 Europe/Paris] PHP  18.
>   Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager->createServiceViaCallback()
>   C:\wamp\www\quickstart\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager.php:1057
>
> [30-Mar-2015 20:29:12 Europe/Paris] PHP  19.
>   call_user_func:{C:\wamp\www\quickstart\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager.php:923}()
>   C:\wamp\www\quickstart\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager.php:923
>
> [30-Mar-2015 20:29:12 Europe/Paris] PHP  20.
>   Album\Module->Album{closure}()
>   C:\wamp\www\quickstart\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager.php:923

Here is my Album\src\Album\Controller\AlbumController.php

```
namespace Album\Controller;

use Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController;
use Zend\View\Model\ViewModel;

class AlbumController extends AbstractActionController
{
protected $albumTable;

public function indexAction()
{
     return new ViewModel(array(
         'albums' => $this->getAlbumTable()->fetchAll(),
     ));
}

public function getAlbumTable()
{
    echo "Made it";
    if (!$this->albumTable) {
        $sm = $this->getServiceLocator();
        echo "Made it";
        if($sm->has('Album\Model\AlbumTable'))
        {
            echo "FOUND Album\Model\AlbumTable";
            $this->albumTable = $sm->get('Album\Model\AlbumTable');
        }else{
           echo "Could not find Album\Model\AlbumTable";
        }
    }
    echo "Made it";
    return $this->albumTable;
}
}
```

Here is Album\Module.php

```
namespace Album;

use Album\Model\Album;
use Album\Model\AlbumTable;
use Zend\ModuleManager\Feature\AutoloaderProviderInterface;
use Zend\ModuleManager\Feature\ConfigProviderInterface;

use Zend\Db\ResultSet\ResultSet;
use Zend\Db\TableGateway\TableGateway;

class Module implements AutoloaderProviderInterface, ConfigProviderInterface
{
    public function getAutoloaderConfig()
    {
    }

    public function getConfig()
    {
        return include __DIR__ . '\config\module.config.php';
    }

    public function getServiceConfig()
    {
        return array(
            'factories' => array(
                'Album\Model\AlbumTable' =>  function($sm) {
                   // echo "inside ftn Album\Model\AlbumTable";
                    $tableGateway = $sm->get('AlbumTableGateway');
                    echo " Gate way GOOD";
                    $table = new AlbumTable($tableGateway);
                    echo "Table good";
                    return $table;
                },
                'AlbumTableGateway' => function ($sm) {
                   // echo "inside ftn AlbumTableGateway";
                    $dbAdapter = $sm->get('Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter');
                  //  echo "adapater good";
                    $resultSetPrototype = new ResultSet();
                    $resultSetPrototype->setArrayObjectPrototype(new Album());
                    return new TableGateway('album', $dbAdapter, null, $resultSetPrototype);
                },
            ),
        );
     }

}
```

Here is  Album\src\Album\Model\AlbumTable.php

```
namespace Album\Model;

use Zend\Db\TableGateway\TableGateway;
//use Zend\Db\ResultSet\ResultSet;

class AlbumTable
{
    protected $tableGateway;

    public function __construct(TableGateway $tableGateway)
    {
        echo "inside construct of AlbumTable";
        $this->tableGateway = $tableGateway;
    }
```

I don't get inside of AlbumTable. I have included it in Module.php with use and the class name and files are spelled correctly. Unless my eyes fail me, and I hope that's the case.

Can anyone tell me why I am getting this error? My out put from the echos are as follows:

**Made it
Made it
FOUND Album\Model\AlbumTable 
Gate way GOOD**

Answer (score 1):

While searching for an answer to my own problem with the in-depth tutorial, I see where in **Album\Module.php** you wrote the following:

```
public function getConfig()
    {
        return include __DIR__ . '\config\module.config.php';
    }
```

When I use those slashes, and reload the index page, I get a blank page. If I **change the slashes** to match what is indicated in the tutorial, like this:

```
     return include __DIR__ . '/config/module.config.php';
```

then the index page loads as expected. You may have other errors, but this much I could test and confirm.

Answer (score 0):

The *class* cannot be found. If you are not using composer (or some other auto loading means) you will need to return the correct configuration in `getAutoloaderConfig` to add the module's namespace to the default  `Zend\Loader\StandardAutoloader`.

```
public function getAutoloaderConfig()
{
    return [
        'Zend\Loader\StandardAutoloader' => [
            'namespaces' => [
                __NAMESPACE__ => __DIR__ . '/src/' . __NAMESPACE__,
            ],
        ],
    ];
}
```

Comment: This actually did not change a the error for me. I removed it because in a video tutorial it said it wasn't required because composer implemented. Here is the video tutorial link - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=suUSXrdUDXQ and it follows along with the zend2 framework tutorial - http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/user-guide/modules.html. I even started a new project and swithced my composer from composer.phar to composer.bat. I am developing in Netbeans.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. In my case, it was because I didn't paste the following line in Module/Album/Module.php:

```
use Album\Model\Album;
```

because it wasn't highlighted in yellow in the tutorial.

You need that line!